# Replace number values in column with assigned text from list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column (dataframe) that has numerical values like the ones shown below:

| Number |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 4 |
| 16 |
| 8 |
| 2 |

I have the next lists:

```
asia = [22, 23, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]    
asia_europe = [8]    
europe = [9, 10, 11, 12]    
europe_america = [13, 14, 15, 16]    
america = [17, 18, 19, 20, 21]
```

I want the numbers in the column to be replaced with their respective text that comes from the lists so that my dataframe looks like this:

| Number | New Column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | asia |
| 2 | asia |
| 4 | asia |
| 16 | europe_america |
| 8 | asia_europe |
| 2 | asia |

I don't know if there is a way to do this using pandas or if I have to use a for loop.

Comment: what have you tried? if you haven't tried anything yet, what do you think is the biggest problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build a dictionary to reference the region from the number. For that a dictionary comprehension is handy:

```
d = dict(asia = [22, 23, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
         asia_europe = [8],
         europe = [9, 10, 11, 12],
         europe_america = [13, 14, 15, 16],
         america = [17, 18, 19, 20, 21])

d2 = {v:k for k,l in d.items() for v in l}
# {0: 'asia',
#  1: 'asia',
#   ...
# 21: 'america'}
```

Then `map` the value to the regions:

```
df['New Column'] = df['Number'].map(d2)
```